# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Sightengine\\SightengineClient' not found in

Tags: php, api, class

after trying different ways of using the API from sightengine I can' get it to work, I followed the instructions on [their site](https://github.com/Sightengine/client-php) , installing via composer, but when I try to use it, I get the Class not found error in apache:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Sightengine\\SightengineClient' not found in /var/www/html/photobooth/app.php
```

PHP file:

`<?php
use Sightengine\SightengineClient;
$client = new SightengineClient('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx');`

Comment: include or require it first

Comment: Hello @Ghost I tried that and it returns the same error, I installed with this command: composer require sightengine/client-php  and I have no idea where it was installed, do I need to run the command from a specific folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed to include the file.

When installing using composer, we have to include the file in our code

```
require_once 'vendor'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoload.php';
```

This will help you to include the file in code, so you can start using the class/objects

Comment: Thank you @Dhayal, I didn't know that, the sample file from them didn't have that, now it works, thanks!